# SAML Authorization Header - not working

Tags: saml-2.0, ws-security, fuseesb, jbossfuse, opensaml

I am trying to deploy a SAML secured service in JBoss Fuse. I have consulted this link - http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-saml.html#JAX-RSSAML-SAMLAssertionValidation.

I would like to use the Authorization header option and so have configured the server and the client as below. I am always getting the exception as "Assertion can not be validated".

Server log -->

Address: http://....
Http-Method: GET
Content-Type: */*

### Headers: {Accept=[*/*], Authorization=[SAML --encoded-string--], Cache-Control=[no-cache], connection=[keep-alive], content-type=[*/*], Host=[localhost:8181], Pragma=[no-cache], User-Agent=[Apache CXF 3.0.4.redhat-620123]}

2015-10-19 16:52:14,536 | WARN  | p1930854886-1149 | AbstractSamlInHandler            | 849 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-rs-security-xml - 3.0.4.redhat-620123 | Assertion must be signed
2015-10-19 16:52:14,536 | WARN  | p1930854886-1149 | AbstractSamlInHandler            | 849 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-rs-security-xml - 3.0.4.redhat-620123 | Assertion can not be validated
2015-10-19 16:52:14,536 | WARN  | p1930854886-1149 | WebApplicationExceptionMapper    | 128 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs - 3.0.4.redhat-620123 | javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toNotAuthorizedException(SpecExceptions.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toNotAuthorizedException(ExceptionUtils.java:134)
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.saml.AbstractSamlInHandler.throwFault(AbstractSamlInHandler.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.saml.AbstractSamlInHandler.validateToken(AbstractSamlInHandler.java:181)
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.saml.AbstractSamlInHandler.validateToken(AbstractSamlInHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.saml.AbstractSamlInHandler.validateToken(AbstractSamlInHandler.java:98)
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.saml.AbstractSamlBase64InHandler.handleToken(AbstractSamlBase64InHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.saml.SamlHeaderInHandler.filter(SamlHeaderInHandler.java:52)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.runContainerRequestFilters(JAXRSUtils.java:1647)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Server -->

```
<jaxrs:server id="service111" address="/saml/test">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref component-id="serviceBean"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger.SwaggerFeature"/>
    </jaxrs:features>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref component-id="jaxbProvider" />
        <ref component-id="jsonProvider" />
        <!-- SAML -->
        <ref component-id="samlHandler"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>

    <!-- SAML -->
    <jaxrs:properties>       
        <entry key="ws-security.signature.properties" value="alice.properties"/>
    </jaxrs:properties>
</jaxrs:server>

<!-- SAML -->
<!-- Authorization Header -->
<bean id="samlHandler" class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.saml.SamlHeaderInHandler"/>
```

Client code -->

public class JavaTestAPI {

```
/*
 * SAML
 */
private WebClient createWebClient(String address) {
    JAXRSClientFactoryBean bean = new JAXRSClientFactoryBean();

    bean.setAddress(address);

    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    /*properties.put("ws-security.callback-handler", "org.apache.cxf.systest.jaxrs.security.saml.KeystorePasswordCallback");
    properties.put("ws-security.saml-callback-handler", "org.apache.cxf.systest.jaxrs.security.saml.SamlCallbackHandler");
    */
    properties.put("ws-security.callback-handler", "org.rest.test.saml.KeystorePasswordCallback");
    properties.put("ws-security.saml-callback-handler", "org.rest.test.saml.SamlCallbackHandler");
    properties.put("ws-security.signature.username", "alice");
    properties.put("ws-security.signature.properties", "alice.properties");
    properties.put("ws-security.self-sign-saml-assertion", "true");
    bean.setProperties(properties);

    bean.getOutInterceptors().add(new SamlHeaderOutInterceptor());

    return bean.createWebClient();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaTestSolrAPI test = new JavaTestAPI();
    String address = "http://localhost:8181/cxf/saml/test/1.0.0?codes=usa,ger&format=json";

    System.out.println("before createWebClient..");
    WebClient wc = test.createWebClient(address);
    System.out.println("wc=" + wc);
    Response resp = wc.get();
    System.out.println("after response=" + resp.getStatus());
    System.out.println("response=" + resp.readEntity(String.class));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the root of your problem, but it appears that the assertion statement you're getting back isn't signed, when it should be.